# Could anyone identify the manufacturer or a similar product to this ~6x7mm inductive charging coil?

Tags: identification, components, coil, inductive, wireless-charging

I had this smart ring from a company called Oura, and I took my charger apart recently. Inside, I found an incredibly small inductive charging coil printed inside of a little FPC.

Could anyone identify where one might acquire such a component? I have tried Googling various markings on the PCB and the little FPC coil, but to no avail. I can't even get the "S" logo to yield anything interesting in reverse image searches. Any help would be appreciated.

---

FPC coil:
[image]

---

PCB top:
[image]

---

PCB bottom:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's custom-made. (There may be over-stock suppliers, though. I wouldn't know.) Do you think it's off-the-shelf for some reason?

Comment: It just looks like a custom  PCB- the markings (backwards UR and 94V-0 flammability rating) are typical. So you'd draw exactly what you want in a suitable program such as Kicad or Altium and have  it manufactured. The stylized S appears on both PCBs - maybe the PCB maker (of which there are thousands) or another company common to both.

Comment: Also suspect it's a custom flex board. See the board below, there is also 'S' logo and bard version 'STD-1'. So it make sense the flex board coded similar as 'STF-3'.