# What is this component used in the Oura Ring charger?

Tags: identification, components

PCB bottom as described in the link：
[Could anyone identify the manufacturer or a similar product to this ~6x7mm inductive charging coil?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/582732/could-anyone-identify-the-manufacturer-or-a-similar-product-to-this-6x7mm-induc)

Does anyone know what the name of the black component in the picture is? The silkscreen is L4ZY 538.

I have thought about it for a long time, but can't speculate what it does. Trying to find the silkscreen is also fruitless.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Answer (score 1):

Before I read your question I had no idea what an Oura Ring is, thanks for telling me. :) Since this is the ring charger, I'm sure the 4 pin component is some kind of a proximity sensor used to detect ring presense when you place it on the charger. Either Hall Effect sensor, or ultrasonic etc.

Try to measure voltages on its pins as you move the ring towards the charger when it's powered. If you see voltage change, definitely it's a pxorimity sensor.

Does the PCB have some sort of induction coil used to charge the ring?

Comment: Oh, and your answer triggered me, so that explains it.

Thank you very much for your answer!

BTW: Does the PCB have some sort of induction coil used to charge the ring?

Yes, between the two is a high frequency wireless charging technology